# Prove $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i!)=(n+1)!-1$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the equality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i!)=(n+1)!-1.
$$
How do you prove this by induction? I have no idea how to start this. How can I approach this, or maybe give me an answer and show me how you did this in detail? Would really appreciate your help, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ we have
$$
LHS=\sum_{i=1}^{1}i(i!)=1
$$
$$
RHS=(1+1)!-1=1
$$
and so $LHS=RHS$. Suppose that the equality holds for $n=k$. We will prove that the equality holds for $n=k+1$. Indeed, for $n=k+1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
LHS&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i(i!)\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i!)+(n+1)(n+1)!\\
&=&(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)!\\
&=&(n+2)!-1\\
&=&RHS.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

You should start by proving the base step:

1. Induction holds for $n=n_0$,
2. Assumption: Induction holds for each $n\in N$
3. Induction step: prove this holds for $n+1$

Step 1:

$n=1$

$$\sum^1_{i=1}i(i!)=1(1!)=1=(1+1)!-1$$

So step 1 holds.

Step 2:

Make an assumption that this holds for some $n$

Step 3:

Move $n$ to $n+1$ and prove using starting equation that it holds:

$$\sum^{n+1}_{i=1}i(i!)=(n+2)!-1$$

$$\sum^{n+1}_{i=1}i(i!)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}i(i!)+(n+1)((n+1)!)=(n+1)!-1+(n+1)((n+1)!)=(n+2)(n+1)!-1=(n+2)!-1$$

so that should be it.